# What should I substitute for shortening: lard or butter?

Tags: baking

My recipe calls for shortening, I want to substitute lard for the shortening, will this work? Or can I just use butter?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/are-there-any-substitutes-for-shortening?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

Yes, and also yes. Moreso lard than butter, as butter has significant water content, but it often does not matter enough to worry about. Most recipes that have been around for a while probably started with lard.

For MOST things, you can simply pick any of the three and it will be fine, or you can mix them if you like.

Comment: The flavor and texture will likely be even better with lard than shortening.

Comment: And an exception  that ecnerwal hinted at -- if it calls for melted butter, you might need to add some water, especially when it's in baking.  (as water will develop gluten, fat won't)

Comment: Totally. Butter is about 16% water. If you modify the fat/liquid calculations by about that much, you should be good.